# How do I prevent error messages when I open other people's android studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am evaluating my fellow coursemate Android Studio project.

WHen I attempt to run, I get the below.

Error message:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.jar
         file:/Users/kim/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.pom
         file:/Users/kim/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.jar
     Required by:
         ModernArtUI:app:unspecified
```

The only way for me to solve the problem is to:

go into their build.gradle (Module: app)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
```

and change to

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"
```

and get this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

change to

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
}
```

How do I avoid having to repeatedly change the build.gradle?

Comment: This is not only in Android studio, this is also in Eclipse ADT. You should already have all dependencies in order to import a project into the IDE. In your case the imported project claimed that it needs compatibility library of version 21.0.3, but seems you do not have it and instead you have v21.0.2 one, so you should either upgrade your compatibility library or lower its version, in order to importing process to be successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the repositories with the SDK Manager.

The error shows that gradle didn't find the app compat library 21.0.3 in your extras/android/m2repository (Android Repository).

Launch the sdk manager and update it and the build tools